# Sql update automatically rolling back or changing after some time

Tags: mysql, azure

I have an Azure SQL db where I am executing a change with a c# call (using `await db.SaveChangesAsync();`)

This works fine and I can see the update in the table, and in the APIs that I call which pull the data. However, roughly 30-40 minutes later, I run the API again and the value is back to the initial value. I check the database and see that it is indeed back to the initial value.

I can't figure out why this is, and I'm not sure how to go about tracking it down. I tried to use the Track Changes SQL command but it doesn't give me any insight into WHY the change is happening, or in what process, just that it is happening.

BTW, This is a test Azure instance that nobody has access to but me, and there are no other processes. I'm assuming this is some kind of delayed transaction rollback, but it would be nice to know how to verify that.

Comment: I should add that I am confident there is no other user process running at this time. I make an update through the API, confirm it worked, check again after 10, it's fine, leave for another 30 minutes, come back and it has reverted. Every single time.

Comment: that is not enough information to go on, a rollback only occurs if a transaction fails, so if you say it run through without error. There can be no rollback. It is probably a backup and restore that is false confgured. try to update more columns tables and so on and see if they also get lost.

Comment: My best guess right now is that it is re-running the Seed method from the Entity Framework configuration. I don't know what would trigger that if I don't do another publish, but I put in a change to the seed method and this time when it removed my changes it went back to what was in the seed method. Any ideas there?

Comment: I would enable the general log and see what is happenig, with the database, there should be nothing till half an hour, so you should get at once what commands where send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

I'm using an Azure Free Tier service, which is done on a shared virtual machine. When the app went inactive, it was being shut down, and restarted on demand when I issued a new request.

In addition, I had a Seed method in my Entity Framework Migration set up to set the particular record I was changing to 0, and when it restarted, it re-ran the migration, because it was configured to do so in my web config.

Simply disabling the EF Migrations and republishing does the trick (or when I upgrade to a better tier for real production, it will also go away). I verified that records outside of those expressly mentioned in the Migration Seed method were not affected by this change, so it was clearly that, and after disabling the migrations, I am not seeing it any more.